# Unowned necessary for type in array?

Tags: swift, syntax, retain-cycle

In the following code, is it necessary to have unowned if the Swift array is passed by value ?

Category has a property for a Swift array, not an Item, so unowned is not necessary right?

```
final class Item: Base {

    unowned let category: Category

    init(value: Int, category: Category) {
        self.category = category
        super.init(value: value)
    }
}

final class Category: Base {

    var items: [Item] = []

}

class Base {

    let name: String

    var index: Int {
        return Int(name)!
    }

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    init(value: Int) {
        self.name = String(value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need `unowned` or `weak`. There's nothing special about arrays that prevents them from being involved in retain cycles.

Arrays simply allow you to reference multiple objects. `myCatgeory.items` can have one element, which is an `Item` that has a `category` that references `myCategory`:

```
let myCategory = Category()
let item = Item(value: 0, category: myCategory)
myCategory.items = [item]
// retain cycle!
```